# Sorting with arrays as values in MongoDB using java mongo db driver api

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query

Sorting with arrays as values in MongoDB

I have collection with two fields, one with string as a value and second array of strings as a value.

e.g.

```
{"name" : "User-1",  "locations" : ["India", "USA", "UK"]}
{"name" : "User-2",  "locations" : ["Russia", "UK", "USA"]}
{"name" : "User-3",  "locations" : ["UK", "Japan", "India"]}
{"name" : "User-4",  "locations" : ["Japan", "USA", "UK"]}
{"name" : "User-5",  "locations" : ["India", "Italy", "Japan"]}
```

I want to sort on field 'locations'.

Output must be

```
{"name" : "User-5",  "locations" : ["India", "Italy", "Japan"]}
{"name" : "User-1",  "locations" : ["India", "USA", "UK"]}
{"name" : "User-4",  "locations" : ["Japan", "USA", "UK"]}
{"name" : "User-2",  "locations" : ["Russia", "UK", "USA"]}
{"name" : "User-3",  "locations" : ["UK", "Japan", "India"]}
```

How can we do that using mongo db java driver api.

Thanks

Comment: If we can use java, I would override the `compareTo` method.

Comment: @Uma. I need to user java driver API, API has sort method.

Comment: @Sarath. Any example code for aggregation.

Comment: @PankajShinde see my answer bro :)

Comment: @Sarath. I got your answer. I want java driver api code. And your code will only sort on first array element.

Comment: @PankajShinde Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the sort with ["dot notation"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) for each item in the array in order:

```
 db.docs.find().sort({ "locations.0": 1, "locations.1": 1, "locations.2": 1 })
```

Which would produce:

```
{ "name" : "User-5", "locations" : [ "India", "Italy", "Japan" ] }
{ "name" : "User-1", "locations" : [ "India", "USA", "UK" ] }
{ "name" : "User-4", "locations" : [ "Japan", "USA", "UK" ] }
{ "name" : "User-2", "locations" : [ "Russia", "UK", "USA" ] }
{ "name" : "User-3", "locations" : [ "UK", "Japan", "India" ] }
```

So it basically considers the preference in order of each element of the array.

With the basic Java API you just supply the same sort argument:

```
collection.find().sort(
    new Document("locations.0",1)
        .append("locations.1",1)
        .append("locations.2",1)
);
```

Comment: But we don't know in advance, number of total array elements. So how can we write code for parameter for sort method mentioned by you.

Comment: @You can specifiy to `n` if you really need to, but just remember that any array that is actually shorter than `n` will always float to the top. Just like sorting on a `null` or missing property of any document.

Comment: "You can specifiy to n", means what. We need to append  n times or use 'n' instead of '0'.

Comment: @PankajShinde Specify each sort key up to the maximum expected. It's better to approach it this way, as if you try to calculate this as you process it will add a lot of overhead. You can always run a separate query to find out the maximum array length before constructing the sort document. But that is a different question to the one that you have asked.

Comment: Ok, Thanks.
Plz correct code for sort order (you mentioned 2 instead of 1) for append function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in mongo console. This uses mongodb aggregation framework:

```
db.users.aggregate({$sort:{'locations':1}})
```

Its surprisingly working for me. I have tested using various test samples. Please check the corner cases if any. Following is one of the test case:

```
> db.users.aggregate({$sort:{'locations':1}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5656ce39cb0a925b3d5d16ea"), "name" : "User-6", "locations" : [ "India", "Italy", "Alabama" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5656ce44cb0a925b3d5d16eb"), "name" : "User-6", "locations" : [ "India", "Italy", "Glabama" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5656ce75cb0a925b3d5d16ed"), "name" : "User-8", "locations" : [ "India", "Italy", "Glabama", "Cloverfield" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5656ce63cb0a925b3d5d16ec"), "name" : "User-7", "locations" : [ "India", "Italy", "Glabama", "Govindam" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5656a65ecb0a925b3d5d16e9"), "name" : "User-5", "locations" : [ "India", "Italy", "Japan" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5656a65ecb0a925b3d5d16e5"), "name" : "User-1", "locations" : [ "India", "USA", "UK" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5656a65ecb0a925b3d5d16e8"), "name" : "User-4", "locations" : [ "Japan", "USA", "UK" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5656a65ecb0a925b3d5d16e6"), "name" : "User-2", "locations" : [ "Russia", "UK", "USA" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5656a65ecb0a925b3d5d16e7"), "name" : "User-3", "locations" : [ "UK", "Japan", "India" ] }
```

In Java API it should be something like this:

```
AggregateIterable<Document> iterable = db.getCollection("users").aggregate(asList(
  new Document("$sort", new Document("locations", 1))));
```

Comment: Thanks Sarath. Your code will work fine. But as I said in question I am using Mongo's Java driver API. And your answer is in query that we will execute on mongo console. Thanks.

Comment: Glad that I could help :) In that case can you please accept it as correct answer